# Initiating objects in a for loop

Tags: java

```
public static int askingAmount() {
    System.out.println("How many persons are there in your company?");
    Scanner amountS = new Scanner(System.in);
    amount = amountS.nextInt();
    System.out.println(amount);
    amountS.close();
    return amount;
}
public static void makingPersons() {
    for (int i=0 ; i<amount ; i++) {
        int personNumber=0;
        Person person[i] = new Person();  //<--- The problem
        System.out.println("person");
    }
}
```

In the first method I was trying to ask the user how many persons they were and then return the amount. In the second I wanted to create an equal amount of Person objects and name them person1, person2, person3 using the variable "i" but I don't get it to work. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Define* the array outside the loop as a class member:

```
Person[] person;
```

Then in the `askingAmount` you initialize it:

```
person = new Person[amount];
```

And inside the loop do:

```
person[i] = new Person();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void makingPersons() {
    Person[] persons = new Person[amount];
    for (int i=0 ; i<amount ; i++) {
        int personNumber=0;
        persons[i] = new Person();  //<--- The solution
        System.out.println("person");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initiate an array of type Person out of the loop and then fill it up with the new instances like so:

```
public static void makingPersons() {

    Person[] person = new Person[amount];

    for (int i=0 ; i<amount ; i++) {
        int personNumber=0;
        person[i] = new Person();
        System.out.println("person");
    }
}
```